# Chrome Extensions: nested folders

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

If use this code:

```
chrome.bookmarks.getTree(function(addNode)
{
    var rootNodeId = addNode[0].children[1].id;
    chrome.bookmarks.create({parentId:rootNodeId, title:'root'}, function(node)
    {
        chrome.bookmarks.create({parentId:node.id, title:'child1'});
        chrome.bookmarks.create({parentId:node.id, title:'child2'});
    });
});
```

to get nested folders they are created but they behave not as normal folders. 
First of all i don't get the little triangle in front of the root folder and if i'm in a subfolder by double clicking and then go back (with browswer arrow) i get to the folder the root folder is contained and not as it should in the root folder.

Any ideas what's wrong with that or is this a bug?

Thanks in advance,
drakon

//EDIT
If i set a breakpoint for the chrome.bookmarks.create line it works as expected. I'm really confused..

//EDIT
Seems to be a bug of chrome -> press F5 lets the entrys appear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you pasted above does what it is expected.

1. You are getting the root node of the "Other bookmarks" folder
2. You are creating a folder called "root"
3. You are creating two child folders inside your parent "root" folder that you already created.

I believe the arrow thing you are seeing is a bug in Chrome, please report it since it should always see that arrow.

Perhaps you are missing some code cause the above works as I explained.

Comment: I realized that if i press F5 in the browser the entrys (and the arrow) appear. So i suppose it's a bug of chrome itself.

Comment: @drakon I realized the similar stuff. I usually reload the extension when weird stuff like this happens. And hit Ctrl + refresh to force it.